# Scala invariant generic type parameter ignored by method parameter type depending whether argument is literal expression versus variable

Tags: scala, generics, casting, type-conversion, covariance

## Summary

If I pass a literal expression as the argument to a function, shouldn't that be the same as first evaluating that same literal expression, then binding a variable to the value returned from that evaluation, and then passing the variable name as the same argument to the same function?  And if that literal expression returns the wrong type for the function's parameter, then skipping the step of assigning the value to an intermediary variable whose type Scala infers from the return value of the expression should not make passing that incompatible type to the function possible where before it raised a type-mismatch error, should it?  Yet is that not what the following example shows?

## Example

Here I try to get a function parameter of type `Array[Super]` to accept a value of `Array[Sub]`.  Declare the following in the Scala repl.  Note the type of the function's single parameter:

```
class Super
class Sub extends Super
def wantsSuperArray(a: Array[Super]) { println(a.size) }
```

Then construct an instance of `Sub`

```
scala> val s = new Sub
s: Sub = Sub@2c9fa2fb
```

Create an `Array[Sub]`:

```
scala> val subArray = Array(s)
subArray: Array[Sub] = Array(Sub@2c9fa2fb)
```

The following would indicate that the generic [`Array` is invariant in its element type](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Array), and that an `Array[Sub]` is not an `Array[Super]` even though a `Sub` is a `Super`:

```
scala> wantsSuperArray(subArray)
<console>:13: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Array[Sub]
 required: Array[Super]
Note: Sub <: Super, but class Array is invariant in type T.
You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: Super`. (SLS 3.2.10)
              wantsSuperArray(subArray)
                              ^
```

No surprises so far.

## Surprising Observation

We just saw that `wantsSuperArray()` will not take as an argument type an `Array[Sub]`.  So why does the following not produce the same type-mismatch error message as above?

```
scala> wantsSuperArray(Array(new Sub))
1
```

Likewise, why raises this no errors?

```
scala> wantsSuperArray(Array(s))
1
```

Consider that the compiler treats the three variants consistently with the repl, namely refusing to compile and giving the same type-mismatch error for the first, and compiling the second and third.

## An Additional Detail

If we expressly parameterize the `Array` as follows then the error message appears again:

```
scala> wantsSuperArray(Array[Sub](new Sub))
<console>:11: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Array[Sub]
 required: Array[Super]
Note: Sub <: Super, but class Array is invariant in type T.
You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: Super`. (SLS 3.2.10)
              wantsSuperArray(Array[Sub](new Sub))
                                        ^
```

So, apparently when there is no intermediate variable involved, Scala can see what type `wantsSuperArray` wants and is doing some kind of conversion, perhaps casting from `Array[Sub]` to `Array[Super]`.  Still, that seems like a gotcha, as I still think that the choice of whether or not to use an intermediate variable should not cause such a difference in a program's operation, and this particular situation seems to be performing a cast instead of raising an error the programmer would be expecting based on the invariance of the generic `Array` type parameter.

## Questions

If I believe that in calling `wantsSuperArray()` as defined above, passing a literal expression ought to be the same as passing the name of a variable holding the value resulting from evaluating that same expression, as show above, then what am I misunderstanding?

- How can I improve my understanding of what I am observing and complaining about here?
- Where in the Scala documentation can I read about the phenomenon I am observing here so as to be able to understand it and never be surprised by it again?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because scala performs type inference base on the expected type of `wantsSuperArray` parameter.
So even though `Array(new Sub)` taken alone would be infered as an expression of type `Array[Sub]`, the compiler sees that you are in the context where a value of type `Array[Super]` is expected, and thus when calling `Array.apply` (which is generic) it tries to  use `Super` as the type parameter (instead of `Sub`), which correctly types (`Array.apply` takes a vararg list of parameters of type `T`, here `T = Super` and you pass an instance of `Sub`, which is a sub-type of `Super`, which is sound).

---

Here is a relevant extract from the scala specification, chapter *6.1: Expression Typing*, chapter *6.6: Function applications* and *chapter 6.26.4: Local Type Inference* (emphasis mine):

> The typing of expressions is often **relative to some expected type (1)** (which might be
>   undefined). When we write “expression e is expected to conform to type T ”, we
>   mean: the expected type of e is T , and the type of expression e must conform
>   to T .
>
> **...**
>
> An application f (e1, ..., em) applies the function f to the argument expressions
>   e1, ..., em. If f has a method type (p1:T1, ..., pn:Tn)U, **the type of each argument
>   expression ei is typed with the corresponding parameter type Ti as expected type (2)**.
>   Let Si be type type of argument ei (i in 1, ..., m). **If f is a polymorphic method, local
>   type inference is used to determine type arguments for f (3)** .
>
> **...**
>
> **If f is a polymorphic method it is applicable if local type inference can
>   determine type arguments so that the instantiated method is applicable (4)***.
>
> **...**
>
> Local type inference infers type arguments to be passed to expressions of polymorphic type. Say e is of type [a1 >: L1 <: U1, ..., an >: Ln <: Un]T and no explicit type
>   parameters are given ... If the expression e appears as a value without being applied to
>   value arguments, **the type arguments are inferred by solving a constraint system
>   which relates the expression’s type T with the expected type pt (5)**

Points (3) and (4) explain how in the expression `Array(new Sub)`, type inference flows from `new Sub` to `Array.apply` to yield the type `Array[Sub]`. This is the "simple" case that you apparently had no problem with. If you just take this rule, `Array(new Sub)` should be typed as `Array[Sub]`. And indeed, it is what happens when it is typed in isolation (by example in `val subArray = Array(new Sub)`, `subArray` does have the type `Array[Sub]`).

But points (1), (2) and (5) together also say that in `wantsSuperArray(Array(new Sub))`, the expected type of the parameter to `wantsSuperArray` (which is `Array[Super]`) is passed to the expression `Array(new Sub)` (because it is an expression of polymorphic type where the type parameter is not explictly given). Thus the expression `Array(new Sub)` is evaluated as the expression `Array[Super](new Sub)`. In other words, it is typed as `Array[Super]`.

Comment: Did you mean to say "it tries to use Super as the type parameter (instead of Sub)"?  The way you wrote it seems like Sub and Super are mistakenly switched.  Am I wrong?

Comment: Doh! Yes of course. This is worrying, it is starting to become an habit for me to say the opposite of what I mean ^^

Comment: Though blessed with one of the fastest minds on SO, you apparently share with me the typing fingers of a mere mortal.  Many thanks for your correct answer, worded so clearly that even the error was plain.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't really do `Array(s)`, since the type information is required, even if it would be `Any`, the compiler will run it's type inference code and detect it can create an `Array[Super]` and it will fit the method call.

When you explicitly say that it's an `Array[Sub]` the compiler is not going to run type inference because you already gave the type yourself and since the type doesn't match the method call it's a compilation error.

Comment: "Since you can't really do Array(s)" => Well you can, given that in his case `s` is `Sub`, the expression `Array(new Sub)` taken in isolation would simply be typed as `Array(Sub)`. The fact that it is typed as `Array[Super]` in his context is because inference also flows in the other direction (from the polymorphic method's parameter type to the passed expression).

Comment: You can't take `Array(s)` in isolation, since it will require type inference that is external to the statement itself.

Comment: By "in isolation" I meant "not in the context of the parameter to `wantsSuperArray`" (I didn't mean "isolated from the defintion of `s`"). By example as in `Array(new Sub)`. `Array(new Sub)` in isolation certainly involves type inference, which flows from `new Sub` to `Array.apply` yielding the type `Array[Sub]`. But when this expression is in the context of the parameter to `wantsSuperArray`, the expected type of the parameter changes from "undefined" when in isolation to `Array[Super]`, which is the reason for the difference in the final inferred type of expression `Array(new Sub)`.